# Is it possible to skip one activity in startActivityForResult?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you skip parts of an Activity stack when returning results in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580558/how-do-you-skip-parts-of-an-activity-stack-when-returning-results-in-android)

I have the following activity stack A->B->C.
A activity has a ui element which starts activity B.
B - is an activity which displays a list and starts activity C. In the activity C user selects some info which should be returned to activity A(B should be dismissed).
Is it possible to call startActivityForResult so that the result will be returned from Activity C to activity A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580558/how-do-you-skip-parts-of-an-activity-stack-when-returning-results-in-android)

Look at using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP there and in the Android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Comment: +1 good to know, my suggestion is just naive ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just delegate the result B gets from C to A? Just call `finish()` after you set the result you received from C on B.